# Trying to read JSON from a text file and send in post request. Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, post, header

I have a file input element on a page. I select a JSON file and then use FileReader to read the contents. I want to then send the contents in a post request. I feel I have tried every possible combination of header parameters and parsing/stringifying the results from the filereader but I either get an empty body in my req.body or I get the error:

SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

I know there are many other posts about this and I have looked through them all but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
// This function is called when the user clicks the upload button after selecting a json file.
 // It reads the contents of the JSON file 
 const upload = async () => {

  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  const data = fileReader.onload = function(e){

    let data = JSON.parse(e.target.result);

    const URL = '/upload';

  fetch(URL, {method: 'POST', headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}, body: {data}}).then((response) => {
    if(!response.ok){
      throw new Error('Something went wrong')
    }     
  }
  )
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e)
  });
  }
  fileReader.readAsText(document.querySelector("#input").files[0], 'UTF-8');

 }
```

And here is the server code

```
app.use(express.json());

// Empty the database and reupload new questions from a JSON file
app.post('/upload',  async (req, res) => {

    // Create client object and wait for connection
    const client = new MongoClient(URL);
    await client.connect();

    // Set database
    const db = client.db('trivia');

    // Remove all data from the database
    db.collection('questions').deleteMany();

    // Repopulate database with new questions
    console.log(req.body);
})
```

I've tried sending the data after parsing, after stringifying, after both. I'm not sure what form I should send it in. Right now based on the syntax error it's being sent as JSON object? The data is an array of JSON objects:

```
[{}, {}, {}] (this format)
```

Comment: Try just `body: e.target.result` and get rid of `let data = JSON.parse(e.target.result);`

Comment: Start by reading the file. Log the content. Once you can see that you know how to read the file, then convert it to JSON. Once you can verify that's working, try sending it to the server. This is just code by praying that things will work.

Comment: I've used loads of logging, I just removed them in my post to focus on the important parts.

Comment: @Titus I get the same result. Logging the data shows the text from the json file

Comment: Can you send the JSON file's content or replicate it with a simpler JSON file?

Comment: What do you mean by the same result ? Do you still get the same `SyntaxError` ? That should not happen if you remove `let data = JSON.parse(e.target.result);`. I've suggested using just `body: e.target.result` because a `Request` body when you want to send JSON has to be a `string` not an `object`.

Comment: I still get the same error

SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: On what line do you get this error ?

Comment: Server is listening on port 8000
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Is my backend trying to parse it when it's coming in or something?

Comment: Oh, I see, I thought the error was on the client side. If you log `e.target.result` on the client side, what do you get ?

Comment: The contents of the json file  
  
[{  
  "_id": {  
    "$oid": "64258e63efb4f9abc656c4b5"  
  },  
  "date": "2023-4-1",  
  "questions": [  
    {  
      "question": "Who played Deputy Marshal Samuel Gerard in the 1993 film   &quot;The Fugitive&quot;?",  
      "answer": "Tommy Lee Jones",  
      "incorrect": [  
        "Harrison Ford",  
        "Harvey Keitel",  
        "Martin Landau"  
      ]  
    },  
  
It's just trivia data. Right now it's an array with 50 objects in it.

Comment: Yes, but what does it look like ? Is it actually JSON ? Does it uses double quotes to quote both the keys and the values ?

Comment: Yes, everything is double quoted. Looks exactly the same as if I just opened the json file in VSCode. The file is formatted properly too because I've imported it to repopulate the db in mongo compass many times